# Baby Rudin Assumptions when dealing with maps

Tags: real-analysis

In a number of theorems, there is no mention of whether a mapping f from a metric space X to Y is injective or surjective. 
 
However, is it assumed that every single element of X does not map to multiple elements of Y? Because from what I've read, the difference between a map and a function is precisely that a single element can be mapped to multiple  elements, whereas such a function would not exist.

Are there any other assumptions involved, if any?

Comment: Most Mathematicians do not distinguish between 'map' and ' function'. Certainly Rudin does not make a distinction. Maps are same as functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is no mention of injectivity or surjectivity then that's because that assumption is not needed.

And for Rudin a map is the same thing as a function. In particular, each object has a single image.